# how to get the object from a redirected view?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, annotations

Im currently using spring mvc, java and annotations.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/submitTask", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView submitTask(HttpSession session, HttpServletRequest request) {
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView(new RedirectView("home.html"));
        map.put("email", request.getParameter("email"));
        map.put("task",request.getParameter("task"));
        map.put("error", request.getParameter("error"));
        model.addObject("map", map);
        return model;
}

@RequestMapping("/home")
 public ModelAndView home(HttpSession session, HttpServletRequest request) {
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("home");
    model.addObject("map", request.getParameter("map"));
    return model;
 }
```

I don't seem to get the value of "map" via "request.getParameter("map")" when i redirected my view to home.html. how can i be able to retrieve it. Thanks

Comment: In you submitTask method, I think you forgot to set the Object to session:

session.setAttribute("map", map);

Comment: It's an incomplete question. Tell us how you are requesting? Whats the URL? and stuff like that.

Comment: im in submitTask.html, so im in the submitTask method

Answer (score 1):

I belive that the problem is that the HttpServletRequest request passed to "home" method contains the parameter "map.email", "map.task", "map.error", but not "map".

Comment: so do you mean, ill get it by using request.getParameter("map.task"), is that what you mean?

Comment: I have taken a look at the implmentation of RedirictView - it looks a bit strange - Try to remove the map indirection: return new RedirectView("home.html", map);  and then access them by request.getParameter("task")  -- this is the last idea i have.

Answer (score 1):

Using `RedirectView` makes the browser issue a new request, so the original request is lost.

You need something like a flash scope or conversation scope. I don't know of any implementation of these, but [check the google results](http://www.google.com/search?hl=&q=flash+scope+spring&sourceid=navclient-ff&rlz=1B3GGLL_en-GB___GB382&ie=UTF-8).

Using spring webflow is a way to handle conversations, but it is too complicated for the simple task.

As a workaround you can use the session, and then clear it immediately (which is essentially what the flash-scope would do)

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
new RedirectView("home.html")
```

to

```
"forward:home.html"
```

Redirect will drop all data on the side of server unless a session attribute or bean as there will be a new request generated from the side of a client.
Forward will transfer everything to a different "method" - request attributes will not be altered, therefore, they will be accessible.